# SearchView does not trigger SearchActivity

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I am having trouble making my SearchView in the ActionBar trigger an intent that is received by my SearchActivity. I think the issue is in the Manifest/XML somewhere, because the logcat isn't even showing the log in the onCreate method of the SearchActivity. I've used [these](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) [resources](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html), and others (including SO responses), to try and implement it, but haven't had any luck.

manifest:

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activitiesFragments.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".activtiesFragments.SearchActivity"/>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activitiesFragments.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/login_button_text"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activitiesFragments.SignUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/create_account_button"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activitiesFragments.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activitiesFragments.SearchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>

</application>
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_messages, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.friends_menu_item).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

SearchActivity

```
package dev.workman.shoutout.activitiesFragments;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import dev.workman.shoutout.R;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> query_results = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView results_view;

    String TAG = "SearchActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        results_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, query_results);
        results_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: created searchview activity");

        handle_intent(getIntent());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        query_results.clear();
        handle_intent(getIntent());
    }

    public void handle_intent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.d(TAG, "handle_intent: query " + query);
            // process the query, add values to the query_results adpater
            // then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Rather than an XML/manifest issue, I the problem lied with the getComponentName() call.

I changed it to

```
new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class)
```

and it works now. I hope this helps others with the same issue